# AWS CDK - Projen noUnusedLocals

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, tsconfig

I am building a CDK library and have everything working, but am planning / iterating through some development and when I do not assign a variable to be used, the CDK will fail on build. I know is not best practice to do this, hence throws a test error, but for purposes of building / saving / testing, need to turn this on. I see in the Projen API docs, the tsconfig API has the noUnusedLocals option (see https://github.com/projen/projen/blob/main/API.md#projen-typescriptcompileroptions) but do not see an option for this in the projenrc.js file or other places. And, cannot directly edit the tsconfig* files since those are protected by projen build. Anyone able to find a way to set the NoUnusedLocals: false?

Answer (score 0):

Add `/* tslint:disable:no-unused-variable */` just before the line that is giving the error.

What also works for some cases, you can name the  parameter name starting with `_`. This will be exempt from the check.
Use `_myVariable` instead of `myvariable` to remove this warning.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the part you like to update in the projen config.

If you want update `noUnusedLocals` to false you can put this snippet to the projen.ts file.

```js
tsconfig: {
    compilerOptions: {
      noUnusedLocals: false,
    },
  },
```

The whole file can than look like this.

```js
import { awscdk } from 'projen';
const project = new awscdk.AwsCdkTypeScriptApp({
  cdkVersion: '2.79.1',
  defaultReleaseBranch: 'main',
  name: 'test-cdk-nag',
  projenrcTs: true,

  deps: ['cdk-nag'], /* Runtime dependencies of this module. */
  // description: undefined,  /* The description is just a string that helps people understand the purpose of the package. */
  devDeps: [], /* Build dependencies for this module. */
  // packageName: undefined,  /* The "name" in package.json. */
  tsconfig: {
    compilerOptions: {
      noUnusedLocals: false,
    },
  },
});
project.synth();
```

The result of `tsconfig.json` and `tsconfig.dev.json` looks like this.

```json
// ~~ Generated by projen. To modify, edit .projenrc.ts and run "npx projen".
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2019"
    ],
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "noEmitOnError": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "stripInternal": true,
    "target": "ES2019"
  },
  "include": [
    ".projenrc.js",
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "test/**/*.ts",
    ".projenrc.ts",
    "projenrc/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```